# Monitor apache connections

Tags: apache, server-side-includes

How do i monitor how many connections apache is getting? Something like http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-server-status/ . Basically i need some tool that will send an email when the number of connections exceed a specified limit. I am not able to find any which would give me the server side statistics of the live server. All that i got is related to simulate the real instance. Please help me if any.

Answer (score 1):

mod_status makes the information available - you just need somethnig to poll the page and report.

[Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) provides a great platform for implementing monitoring (scheduling / alerting / reporting / escalation / automatic responses), while there are at least 2 plugins ([check_apachestatus.pl](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Tutorials/Other-Tutorials-And-HOWTOs/Monitoring-Apache-Session-load-with-Nagios-through-mod_status/details) and [check_apache2.sh](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Web-Servers/Apache/check_apache2-2Esh/details)) which will report on concurrent connections.

Comment: check_apache2.sh seems to be what i need but will it send a mail if the server load exceeds a particular limit